# How to use a value entered in a text box in GTK?

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I have a textbox asking for a value. How can I capture this value and pass on this to another function?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkWidget *window,*table,*label,*entry;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  //Create the main window
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  initialize_window(window);

   /* Create a 1x2 table */
   table = gtk_table_new (1, 2, TRUE);
   gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);

  /* create a new label. */
  label = gtk_label_new ("Enter some text:" );
  //gtk_misc_set_alignment (GTK_MISC (label), 0, 0);
  gtk_table_set_homogeneous(GTK_TABLE (table), TRUE);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), label, 1, 2, 0, 1);

  //create a text box
  //  entry = gtk_entry_new ();
  gtk_entry_set_max_length (GTK_ENTRY (entry),0);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), entry, 0, 1, 0, 1);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}
```

Now I want to use this value and pass it to some function.

Comment: When do you want to access the text? upon the firing of a signal?

Comment: @moter ya as the value is enterd in textbox ,i need this value and pass it to another function which is basically my algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  When the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, `entry_activated` will be called:

```
static void entry_activated(GtkEntry *entry, gpointer user_data)
{
    int i;
    const gchar *entered = gtk_entry_get_text(entry);

    i = atoi(entered); // strtol() would be better, but this will work.

    g_message("Entry: %d", i);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* ... stuff ... */

    entry = gtk_entry_new();
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(entry_activated), NULL);

    /* ... stuff ... */
}
```

Comment: i need an integer value i,and pass it to hello(i);     can u tell me how to modify ur code for that

Comment: static void entry_activated(GtkEntry *entry, gpointer user_data)
{
    const gchar *entered = gtk_entry_get_text(entry);
    
    int i=(int)entered;
    
    
    g_print("Entry: %d",i );

//    g_free(i);
}

Comment: when i try to do this it is giving me garbage value

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, if all you want is a numerical value you'd be better off using GtkSpinButton in the first place. Then you wouldn't have to go through the trouble of converting the string. As it stand now, the user could still enter any text and possibly screw up your program.

You can create a SpinButton easily with

```
GtkWidget *sbutton = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range(<minimum>, <maximum>, <step>);
```

and then connect to the "value-changed" signal. Then just extract the value with

```
gdouble value = gtk_spin_button_get_value(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(sbutton));
```